# Trim and allign an output of command in expect script

Tags: bash, scripting, shell-scripting, expect

```
{ echo ' ' ;echo ' IP : ' ;ip route get 8.8.8.8 | cut -d' ' -f7,8 | tr -d 'src' ;echo ' ' ;dmidecode -t bios | grep -iw 'Version' ;echo ' ' ;}
```

the output of above command mentioned is:

IP :
10.0.0.1

```
    Version: 1.8
```

but i want to allign it properly example below:

IP:10.0.0.1|Version:1.8

kindly help this is an urgent request.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You mean you need the output to be `IP:$YOUR_IP|Version:$BIOS_VERSION`?

Comment: yes,i need same as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
echo "'IP:$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep '\<via\>' | awk '{print $7}')|Version:$(dmidecode -t bios | grep -iw Version | awk '{print $2}')'"
```

Note that it's not considering that `ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep '\<via\>'` or `dmidecode -t bios | grep -iw Version` might return more than one line.

Comment: your command is working fine when i am running as a command but in expect script giving error
```set XYZ "{ echo "'IP:$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $7}')|Version:$(dmidecode -t bios | grep -iw Version | awk '{print $2}')"} >/tmp/Version_info_$NOW.log_$host.csv"

i am storing the output in a file.

Comment: I couldn't get why you need the `set XYZ`. Isn't running the `echo "..." > /your/file.csv` enough? Probably you're having issues because the quotes aren't escaped.

Comment: ok i got you @Gustavo thanks for your help